# jsonapi-resources: Key is not included in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller, jsonapi-resources

When testing my controllers (that use [jsonapi-resources](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources)), on update I have been bumping into this error.

```
{\"errors\":[{\"title\":\"Key is not included in URL\",\"detail\":\"The URL does not support the key 946591862\",\"id\":null,\"href\":null,\"code\":\"110\",\"source\":null,\"links\":null,\"status\":\"400\",\"meta\":null}]}
```

An example of the code the makes the request

```
process :update, method: :post, params: {
  id: model_id,
  data: update_attributes
}
```

I'm just writing basic ActionController::TestCase tests.
the update_attributes method follows the following format:

```
{
  id: model_id,
  attributes: attributes,
  type: model_type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah. The issue I have is that I was using different ids inside and outside the data hash.